# Force WMD to use built-in preprocessor

Tags: javascript, markdown, wmd, wmd-markdown

I use [wmd](https://github.com/caolan/wmd) to all my projects but lately I wanted to add support for fenced code blocks and I saw that it is possible to achieve with preprocessors. I'm using something like this:

```
const content = wmd(myMarkdownString, {preprocessors: ['fencedCodeBlocks']});
```

But it doesn't work - throws error:

```
TypeError: fn is not a function
```

As I understand, I should pass there a function instead of string? But when I try to do it, I'm getting an error that `fencedCodeBlocks` variable is undefined but I don't know which object contain this method exactly (tried different options but without success).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the `wmd` module documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wmd):

> `wmd.preprocessors`: An object containing core preprocessor functions:
>
> - fencedCodeBlocks - GitHub style fenced code blocks

So the code should be:

```
const content = wmd(myMarkdownString, {preprocessors: [wmd.preprocessors.fencedCodeBlocks]});
```

Comment: I feel so ashamed that I've misunderstood that line properly earlier. Thank You for help - it worked!